# Cannot use trackpad and keyboard at the same time

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, touchpad

My trackpad works fine, but the moment I press a button on my keyboard, the mouse freeze and I can not use my trackpad anymore. When I release the key the trackpad works again. This is an issue for some software where I would like to continue using my keyboard while moving the mouse

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 on a DELL laptop

Output of `xinput list-props` for the touchpad id

```
Device 'DELL07E6:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (172):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (174): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (327): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (328): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (329):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (330):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (331):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (332):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (333):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (334):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (311):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (312):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (335):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (336):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (313):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (314):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (315):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (337): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (338):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (339):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (340):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (341):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (318): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (319): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (323): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (324): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (292): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (293):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (294):    0, 0
    Device Node (295):  "/dev/input/event10"
    Device Product ID (296):    1739, 30383
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (325):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (326):   1
```

Comment: Yes it works now thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `xinput` and note down the touch- or trackpad ID.

- Execute

  ```
  xinput set-prop <id> 'libinput Disable While Typing Enabled' 0
  ```
- Or, as you did, list its properties with `xinput list-props <id>`, note down the property number of the "Disable While Typing Enabled"
  line (in your case 335) and execute

  ```
  xinput set-prop <id> <property> 0
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to the above solution, which did not work for me.

After installing `gnome-tweaks` I was able to use the GUI to manually alter the setting `Disable while typing`.

1. Install gnome-tweaks with:
   `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
2. After installing, open gnome-tweaks by typing in your terminal:
   `gnome-tweaks`
3. Navigate to **Keyboard and Mouse** Tab.
4. Under **Touchpad**, unselect option *Disable While Typing*.

Hope this helps!